# How to perform 2 functions one after the other with forEach, without looping twice?

Tags: javascript, loops, foreach

Does anyone know how can I do the same thing as that :

```
Player.list.forEach(player => {
    player.firstLayer();
});

Player.list.forEach(player => {
    player.secondLayer();
});
```

But looping it only one time to make it faster.

(I want to execute all firstLayer function of all players, and then execute secondLayer function, but without looping it Player.list two times)

Thanks for answer.

Comment: I don't see how that would be possible…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible and there is no real difference in performance. The Big O notation is a mathematical notation that describes the limiting behavior of a function when the argument tends towards a particular value or infinity. There is no difference between running over the loop once or twice. The difference of O(n) vs O(2n) in terms of asymptotic complexity doesn't exist since both have the "linear" growth rate.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can do is

```
Player.list.forEach(player => {
  player.firstLayer();
  player.secondLayer();
});
```

but this will execute directly the second layer immediately after the first layer for each element. If the second layer for every element is different you cannot do what you want without looping again.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that the first looped player secondLayer function will be performed before the last looped player firstLayer function. I want to do all firstLayer and then secondLayer

Comment: If you want to get all the functions from the player you need to do a for each. Because the loop allow you to access the data for each player you have.
There is no solution to your problem. 
PS: In case your problem is that the data is inside a server so you don't want to send a data request 2 times to the server you have to assign all the player list to a variable that next you can use to loop through. This is the only occasion where you can speed up the process. But still you will end using 2 for each